# Installing Varnish 4.1 on Debian Jessie i686

Tags: apache, debian, varnish, debian-jessie, varnish-4

I cannot find a simple way to install Varnish 4.1 on Debian Jessie i686 through command line. This is an OpenVZ VPS.

```
apt-get install varnish
```

only installs 4.0.2 and upgrade and dist-upgrade do not affect it.

Using the quick and manual installation instructions for 4.1 do not work either. I uninstalled and autoremoved varnish 4.0.2, then followed this step by step https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish41/install#manual-deb.

It didn't actually install anything because **varnishd -V** says it does not exist. **apt-get install varnish** just installs the 4.0.2 version again.

Every other tutorial I visit is using "repo.varnish-cache.org" which is defunct or says that the tutorial doesn't work for i686 version of Debian.

I only mess around on this VPS once in a while so I'm a bit of a newbie with Linux commands and need really clear documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try the automated way: https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish41/install#bash-deb

```
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/varnishcache/varnish41/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
apt-get install -y varnish
```

just tested it in a fresh docker container, works beautifully